# How do I pass a Grails Arbitrary Variable defined in the URL Mapping to a controller?

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I have the following URL Mapping:

```
"/Manage" {
   controller = "portal"
   action = "login"
   app = "directoryManagement"
}
```

In the above snippet, app is an arbitrary embedded variable as described here: http://docs.grails.org/2.5.0/guide/single.html#embeddedVariables

The portal controller is a child of the authentication controller. All the login action does in the portal controller is call the login action of the authentication controller.

However, in the authentication controller, I am unable to access the embedded arbritary variable

```
params.app
```

I have been at this for hours and it seems like I'm missing something simple. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code should work for anyone that is trying to pass an arbitrary variable to a controller. I had a typo in my URL mapping which is why I wasn't seeing the 'app' parameter in my authentication controller.

Comment: That doesn't sound right.  From looking at the code sample, I think you either need to change the curly braces to parens, or change the colons to equal signs.  Either should work.  The syntax shown there should not work.

Comment: And there is a quote missing after `"/Manage`.

Comment: I don't think it is possible that that code sample works as it is currently written.